# Enclose a dict into a list only if it is not already inside a list

Tags: python

I'm certain my google-fu is just off. But I cannot find the solution I'm searching for. I've come up with an answer, however, I'm sure there is a much better way of doing things. This is in relationship to flasks `request.get_json()` method, if this provides any better recommendations.
I'm looking to do the following conversion. "input" is the result of `request.get_json()`. I assume output is self-explanatory.

```
input: {'a':1, 'b':2}
output: [{'a':1, 'b':2}]

input: [{'a':1, 'b':2}]
output: [{'a':1, 'b':2}]

input [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':1, 'b':2}]
output: [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':1, 'b':2}]
```

So far my wokring example is:

```
input = isinstance(input, dict) and [input] or input
```

I've already tried the following:

```
input = [input] 
# results in nested list if already list [[input]]

input = [item for item in input] 
# results in using input.keys() in list so ['a', 'b'] if only a dict
```

Maybe I am using the best method. It's possible, but it just doesn't seem... I don't know pythonic? Efficient? Very professional? I'm not really sure. There just seems like there should be a better way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function seems pythonic enough:

```
def enclose(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return [d]
    return d
```

I know it's the `[d]` that can throw someone off *(I don't really enjoy it in my code, but I still use it)*, but there are times when it's just what we need to do.

Note: It is considered a bad practice to name variables names that are already taken by built-in methods, even if you aren't going to use the methods. I would recommend you name that `input` variable into, say, `user_input`.

Comment: It was just the first name that popped into my head as a quick 'obvious this is where the information is coming form'. You are correct though, in usual code it isn't named that. Also, thank you for editing the message to show that back ticks create small sections of 'code-style' input. Wasn't aware of that. Have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is a bit cryptic and uses the specifics of how boolean operators work in Python. You could use a conditional expression instead:

```
input = [input] if isinstance(input, dict) else input
```

This will be easier to read for most. Some will argue that the else case is really spurious noise as it amounts to `input = input`, so a simple `if` would be what I'd expect a team member to write if they were friendly =)

```
if isinstance(input, dict):
    input = [input]
```

Then nobody has to stare down what's happening and why.

Comment: Ended up with the above enclose function since it us used quite frequently. But I like the if / else on a single line too. Much obliged! Have a great day!